# How to use structured data (JSON-LD) for a local business that is made up of several sub businesses

Tags: json-ld, structured-data

I built a website for a local business that has a golf course, indoor sports complex (tennis, racquetball, wally ball, batting cages, nautilus), a restaurant, does catering, and offers weddings and receptions. Not sure how to get started. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I assume you mean the vocabulary Schema.org? Anyway, this question is too broad. Stack Overflow is appropriate if you have a specific question or a problem with what you have tried. Maybe [this answer on Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/92108/17633) SE helps you how to find suitable Schema.org types.

Comment: You need to provide more context.  What are you trying to accomplish.  Are you writing an API? Are you implementing SEO? etc...

Answer (score 2):

Good Afternoon,

The following example might be helpful. Please note, for @id I've made the assumption that you've created a dedicated page for each entity and indicated that link in the example but it doesn't have to be a working link therefore if you haven't created a dedicated page you can create a unique id for each entity (this id should not change over time). Please see definitions of department and subOrganization at [schema](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness).

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{ 
  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "LocalBusiness",
  "name" : "Business Name",
  "@id" : "http://www.your-company-site.com",
  "logo" : "http://www.your-company-site.com/logo.jpg",
  "sameAs" : [ "", "" ],
  "url" : "http://www.your-company-site.com",
  "email" : "example@your-company-site.com",
  "faxNumber" : "+1-401-555-1213",
  "contactPoint" : { 
    "@type" : "ContactPoint",
    "telephone" : "+1-401-555-1212",
    "contactType" : "customer service"
  },
  "openingHoursSpecification": [
    {
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": [ "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" ],
    "opens": "09:00",
    "closes": "21:00"
    },
    {
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": [ "Saturday", "Sunday" ],
    "opens": "10:00",
    "closes": "23:00"
    }
  ],
  "department" : [
    {
    "@type" : "GolfCourse",
    "name" : "Golf Course Name",
    "@id" : "http://www.your-company-site.com/golf-course-dedicated-page-url",
    "logo" : "http://www.your-company-site.com/logo.jpg",
    "sameAs" : [ "", "" ],
    "url" : "http://www.your-company-site.com/golf-course-dedicated-page-url",
    "email" : "golfcourse@your-company-site.com",
    "faxNumber" : "+1-401-555-1215",
    "contactPoint" : { 
      "@type" : "ContactPoint",
      "telephone" : "+1-401-555-1214",
      "contactType" : "customer service"
    },
    "openingHoursSpecification": [
      {
      "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
      "dayOfWeek": [ "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" ],
      "opens": "09:00",
      "closes": "19:00"
      },
      {
      "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
      "dayOfWeek": [ "Saturday", "Sunday" ],
      "opens": "09:00",
      "closes": "17:00"
      }
    ]
    },
    {
    "@type" : "TennisComplex",
    "name" : "Tennis Complex Name",
    "@id" : "http://www.your-company-site.com/tennis-complex-dedicated-page-url",
    "logo" : "http://www.your-company-site.com/logo.jpg",
    "sameAs" : [ "", "" ],
    "url" : "http://www.your-company-site.com/tennis-complex-dedicated-page-url",
    "email" : "tenniscomplex@your-company-site.com",
    "faxNumber" : "+1-401-555-1216",
    "contactPoint" : { 
      "@type" : "ContactPoint",
      "telephone" : "+1-401-555-1215",
      "contactType" : "customer service"
    },
    "openingHoursSpecification": [
      {
      "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
      "dayOfWeek": [ "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" ],
      "opens": "09:00",
      "closes": "19:00"
      },
      {
      "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
      "dayOfWeek": [ "Saturday", "Sunday" ],
      "opens": "09:00",
      "closes": "17:00"
      }
    ]
    }
  ],
  "subOrganization" : {
    "@type" : "Restaurant",
    "name" : "Restaurant Name",
    "@id" : "http://www.your-company-site.com/restaurant-dedicated-page-url",
    "logo" : "http://www.your-company-site.com/logo.jpg",
    "sameAs" : [ "", "" ],
    "url" : "http://www.your-company-site.com/restaurant-dedicated-page-url",
    "email" : "restaurant@your-company-site.com",
    "faxNumber" : "+1-401-555-1217",
    "contactPoint" : { 
      "@type" : "ContactPoint",
      "telephone" : "+1-401-555-1216",
      "contactType" : "customer service"
    },
    "openingHoursSpecification": [
      {
      "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
      "dayOfWeek": [ "Monday", "Tuesday" ],
      "opens": "11:30",
      "closes": "22:00"
      },
      {
      "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
      "dayOfWeek": [ "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" ],
      "opens": "11:30",
      "closes": "23:00"
      },
      {
      "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
      "dayOfWeek": [ "Saturday", "Sunday" ],
      "opens": "16:00",
      "closes": "23:00"
      }
    ]
  }
}
</script>
```